Bluetooth eyeglass frames to interact with mobile phones
I am looking for a set of chargeable USB C eyeglasses, with Bluetooth, such that it is possible to do and program a phone in such a way that making it closer to the face with glasses enlarges or minimizes the font. Or, interacts in novel zooming and panning ways, also, according to phone orientations.
This could be useful to eyeglass makers, opticians, and eyeglass afficionados.
Where can I find this?
(such an app could keep track of distance between the phone and the eyeglass frame, the eyeglass orientimaton, and the phone orientation (also relative to each other) and it would be a cuddle if the eye frame was comfortable and not too light or not too heavy (and, of course, if the lenses were comfortable (and, didn't do harm, in the long run))).
Thanks.
Thanks.
Please migrate my phone to the internet of things (IoT) stack exchange if more appropriate there.
